# Outputting a png or pdf file for an animated plot receiving streamed data

Tags: matplotlib

I am currently streaming two integers from a microsensor to my laptop and using those two integers to make an animated plot with respect to time. I was wondering if matplotlib can output a file of the graph for the duration of the stream.

Comment: I know this isn't quite what you asked for, but I hope this is helpful (in case you didn't know about it). It's quite easy to make an animated plot with matplotlib. There is a library for it. You can make an mp4 file depicting the animation or even a GIF relatively easily.  Check out this small example: http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/save-matplotlib-animations-as-gifs/

Comment: This is very useful thank you!